# Next.js Fetch API cannot load webpack:///./pages/index.js?. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request

Tags: navigation, next.js

[image]

Hello! I used Next.js(9.1.1) in my project for the first time. 
After the initial load of main page, it's okay to navigate to other pages by Link(provided by Next.js), which is client side navigation.

But, when I navigate to the main page by Link, I got the errors like the ones in the pic at the top. Then, the main page is refreshed and rendered properly, which is the case in the development environment.

In production mode, it is not refreshed and it shows the error with this simple message "An unexpected error has occurred."

I have no clue to sort out this issue now. I guess getInitialProps may cause this problem. getInitialProps in Main page is differect from getInitialProps in other pages.

```
Main.getInitialProps = async ({ store }) => {
    await store.dispatch({
        type: LOAD_POSTS_REQUEST
    });
    await store.dispatch({
        type: LOAD_RANDOM_POSTS_REQUEST
    });
};
```

```
Category.getInitialProps = async context => {
    const category_name = context.query.category_name;
    // console.log("Search querystring : ", keyword);
    if (category_name !== "undefined") {
        context.store.dispatch({
            type: LOAD_CATEGORY_POSTS_REQUEST,
            category: category_name
        });
    }

    return { category_name };
};
```

And this is the Link on header for navigation to the main page:

```
<Link href="/">
<a>BouqPost</a>
</Link>
```